# Magento 2 - How to reflect immediately product stock updates on frontend which happens when the visitor loads product details page?

Tags: magento2.4, full-page-cache

I wanted to update my product qty and price details when a visitor visits a product details page.

To do this I used observer event 'catalog_controller_product_init_after' in MyMagento\app\code\MyCompany\StockManager\etc\frontend\events.xml and call an observer class.

In my observer class it triggers as expected and pulls product details from an external ERP system API and performs the update.

As far as the desired functionality, this solution works fine. I see the product qty and price get updated each time when a visitor visits the product page.

But the problem is, the product qty/price update does not reflect in the initial page load even though product qty/price is updated in the backend.

The new qty/price only reflects when the same product page is refreshed second time.

From admin I have disabled Full page cache thinking this could be the reason for not reflecting th e immediate changes. But its not.

So I would like to know is there anything I can do to make this real time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can anyone give me a suggestion please?

Comment: Maybe because it is an after event? So, you are doing all the changes after the product has been initialized? Haven't worked with this event before, so, can't help more. But, it looks like you are making the changes too late?
Also, you are calling this API every time the customer is visiting the product page? Would there be an option for you to send updates to Magento from the ERP whenever a product has changed? Because, usually, products do not change so often and making an API call on each page load is expensive

Comment: Hi @DanStaver, The event I'm using is 'catalog_controller_product_init_after'. Perhaps you are correct. I must try an event which happens before the init process. Regarding the API call for every visit to the page, unfortunately yes. Because we are restricted to relay on Magento side to update product qty rather than pushing the changes to it from ERP end. The reason is we have no control over the ERP system that we work with.  I know this is costly but for now we have no other options other than developing in this way.  Thank you.